# Calculating the gain of a specific transistor amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, gain, bipolar, small-signal

[image: Transistor Amp]

NOTE: There is an error in the drawing above — C<sub>1</sub> should be connected to the emitter, not the collector.

Hi Electronics SE, hope this is the right place to ask this, if not I'll gladly take it down and move to a different resource.

Yesterday during a practical lab exam on bipolar transistor circuits, the pictured amp was given. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the gain value, and just couldn't figure it out.

The main problem was not being able to express v(1) without parameters of the second transistor stage (mainly v(eb2)). What would be the correct approach in analyzing this circuit in the small-signal (AC) regime? The early effect is neglected.

[image: Small Signal (AC) Regime]

I'm pulling my hair out over not being able to solve this, would I need to create a system of equations with both gains of each stage and solve it that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What about the DC bias of the first stage? Is it contained in the signal source? 2. The collector of the 2nd transistor is connected to ground (or must C1 be connected to the emitter??) 3. Do you really need a small-signal equivalent diagram for writing down corresponding formulas? Formulas for common-emitter stages are readily available. 4. The input resistance of the 2nd stage appears in parallel to the collector resistor of the first stage - that`s all!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

1) Yes, the DC bias is provided by a signal offset U(0)

2) That's my bad, C(1) was probably connected to the emitter (I drew the diagram from memory) 

3) Yes, the small-signal analysis was required for points

4) Does that mean that I can write:
\$v_1 = (R_{c1} || R_{in2}) \cdot g_{m1}\cdot v_{be1}\$
Which would get rid of the \$v_{eb2}\$ term?

Comment: No - the gain is drastically reduced due to the emitter resistor \$R_{E1}\$ (negative feedback). The reduction factor is \$\frac{1}{1+g_{m1}\cdot R_{E1}}\$.

Comment: Here is something to consider.  The emitter current is the sum of the base and collector currents.  For example, if the transistor has a gain of 99, then the collector current is 99% of the emitter current.  That plus Ohm's Law ...

Comment: There is attenuation from each stage loading the previous and non-linearity,  not so precise, as Av= - Rc/Re  and RL must be > Re2

Comment: @NicolasZaugg You have a voltage divider at the T1 base which attenuates the input signal to T1, RE1*(beta1+1)/(RS+RE1*(beta1+1)). This is followed by the T1 gain, roughly (RC1||(RE2*(beta2+1)))/(RE1+re1). This is followed by a small divider at the tip of your emitter follower T2, which is RE2/(RE2+re2). And this is followed by another divider, RL/(RL+RE2). That should get close, ignoring the early effect.